# How to write the following code with less lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have 2 `<ul>` 's with 3 `<li>`'s on each. I want to change the color of a specified `<li>` on the second `<ul>` when I hover over a specified `<li>` on the first `<ul>`. And when I do not hover the element, I want the format to change back to normal. Here is my code:

```
<ul class="a">
 <li class="a1"></li>
 <li class="a2"></li>
 <li class="a3"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="b">
 <li class="b1"></li>
 <li class="b2"></li>
 <li class="b3"></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document.ready(function() {
   $(".a1").mouseover(function(){
        $(".b1").css({"color":"red","font-size":"19px"});
    });
   $(".a1").mouseout(function(){
        $(".b1").css({"color":"#045491","font-size":"16px"});
    });
   $(".a2").mouseover(function(){
        $(".b2").css({"color":"red","font-size":"19px"});
    });
   $(".a2").mouseout(function(){
        $(".b2").css({"color":"#045491","font-size":"16px"});
    });
   $(".a3").mouseover(function(){
        $(".b1").css({"color":"red","font-size":"19px"});
    });
$(".a3").mouseout(function(){
        $(".b1").css({"color":"#045491","font-size":"16px"});
    });

    });
</script>
```

So my question is, how can I perform the above with less code? Ive tried some toggle/add,remove methods but I could not get it to work. The code above does work, but I feel like it can be performed with less lines of code. Thank you.

Comment: wouldnt you want `.b3` within the `.a3` functions?

Comment: I only included those class names for the purpose of this question!!

Comment: @Walt - that's a problem then as the pattern in the class names could be fundamental to answering the question the way it is written.

Comment: ^ There's that, the classNames are instrumental, if you just wanted an index based solution, say so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.index` since your `class` names are all the same besides the number and add/remove a `class`:

**JS**

```
$(".a").find("li").hover(function(){
   var index = $(this).index()+1; 
    $(".b"+index).addClass("active")  
}, function(){
    $(".b").find("li").removeClass("active")
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
   color: red;
   font-size: 19px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4ohvuwr/1/)

## **UPDATE**

I saw your comment about the `class` names just being an example, I adjusted my code still using `.index()` this way the class name of `li` is irrelevant and it will highlight the corresponding `li` in the same position of `ul.b` **UPDATE** I switched to James Gaunt's suggestion of `eq()` **AND** StevenL's to use `.toggleCLass`. I like both of those better than using `nth-of-type()` and a hover out function:

```
$(".a").find("li").hover(function(){
   var index = $(this).index(); 
   $(".b").find("li").eq(index).toggleClass("active");
});
```

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4ohvuwr/4/)

Comment: You should be able to fairly easily modify this to have no dependency on the list item class names, e.g. $(".b" + index) => $(".b li").eq(index)

Comment: Yep did so with `nth-of-type` but could have used `.eq` too

Comment: I'll see you're awesome, clean solution and up you a toggleClass():

$(".a").find("li").hover(function(){
   var index = $(this).index(); 
   $(".b").find("li").eq(index).toggleClass("active");
});

Comment: @StevenL great idea, not sure why i didnt think of that. Updated my post

Comment: @jmore I was in the process of coming up with a really convoluted solution to this problem. I was bundling the traits in an object, and passing them around... glad I refreshed.

Comment: Haha i've done that too, sometimes the best solutions are very easy

Comment: @jmore009 @StevenL @James Gaunt  Thanks a lot guys! I understand the code above, but i need to do more homework on eq and index! I'm absolute rookie. I should have mentioned this as well but I would like for the code to not be dependent on the `<li>` position. For example, what if I wanted to add the active class to b2 when I hovered over a1? or add active to b1 when I hovered over a3. should I create if statements for that? or maybe a new index variable for each scenario? Thank you in advance

Comment: @StevenL question above. I dont think that last comment tagged you.

Comment: @JamesGaunt question above. I dont think that last comment tagged you.

Comment: @Walt - I would raise another question for this, and make sure it's clear what you want it to be able to do.  When you write out the code "the long way" it's relatively easy to just switch around the way it works. But if you want something short and compact the way to write that will depend on the specific requirements, each different requirement may result in quite different short code. Generalised/easy to modify code is generally long/verbose where as code for very specific scenarios can be made much shorter.

Comment: There's two ways that come to mind, 1) I'd create an object to associate, so no rewriting the code for each one. Object Oriented code design can be daunting at first 2) HTML short cut: adding a data-attribute of which selector (class or id) to target. So the mouse'd over one would look like <div id="a1" data-target-selector="#b2".  Then the jQuery Selector would look like $(this.attr("data-target-selector"))... Bad form, but it gets the job done when you haven't completely learned a bunch of stuff about inheritance and such. Though, it could be a good excuse to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

at lease, you can 'extract code' for css and 'make the chain call' for js:

origin js

```
$(".a1").mouseover(function(){
    $(".b1").css({"color":"red","font-size":"19px"});
});
$(".a1").mouseout(function(){
    $(".b1").css({"color":"#045491","font-size":"16px"});
});
```

to new js:

```
$(".a1").mouseover(..).mouseout(...);
```

change your origin css code:

```
mouse_over_style = {"color":"red","font-size":"19px"}
mouse_out_style = {"color":"#045491","font-size":"16px"}
```

then change your js to:

```
$('.b1').mouseover(mouse_over_style).mouseout(mouse_out_style)
```

Comment: You could abstract all that CSS out into a CSS class to keep the JS clean. Then simply use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`...

Comment: @War10ck wow this helps a lot. My entire goal here was to add different scenarios when I hover over a specific `<li>` in the first list. i.e I want to change the font/color of b2 and b3 when I hover over a1. or change the font/color of b2 when I hover over a3. I forgot that you can create a class in css w/o it being on the html. Then simply running .removeClass() and addClass() to whatever scenario I want. rookie mistake by me. So thank you and @Siwei Shen!